# How to login to server and then hit a url on the same server to get JSON in return

Tags: java, json

Whenever I try to hit a url using java it will redirect me to login page. How can I first login then hit a specific url to get JSON in return ?

Here what I tried so far:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(GET_EXPENSE_FOR_VENDOR_URL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
    String response;

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(response);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        gson.fromJson(response, ExpenseAllocationDTO[].class);
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<ExpenseAllocationDTO>>() {
        }.getType();

        expenseAllocationList = gson.fromJson(response, collectionType);
        expenseAllocationDTODataModel = (new ExpenseAllocationDTODataModel(expenseAllocationList));

        if (expenseAllocationList.isEmpty() || expenseAllocationList == null) {
            expenseExists = true;
        }

        conn.disconnect();
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: A shortcut method would be to use Selenium. See http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: 1. this code isn't readable at all. There is no indention at all, please format it properly. 2. as far as i see this code wouldn't compile

Comment: And this code is not jsf related either and not java-se and not json/gson. Rather http. Please improve your question. Remove redundant code, try from a main class etc..

Comment: Well, I'm so not a RTFM guy, but you've got to back up a bit and understand what you're dealing with. Is the server expecting session/logged-in info in a cookie or in a header value? I'd agree that you should try something like Selenium or better yet, [Ghost Inspector](https://ghostinspector.com)

Answer (score 0):

### The problem

I believe the initial request is missing some headers. Only the `Accept` header is set.

### How to solve it ?

#### Option #1

In order to discover the missing headers, open your favorite browser and browse to `GET_EXPENSE_FOR_VENDOR_URL`. Before browsing, open the webdeveloper toolbar in order to see headers sent by the browser.

Here is a sample screenshot of the webdeveloper toolbar under Chrome on Windows.
[image: webdeloper headers tab - Chrome].

#### Option #2

If your browser doesn't have such a toolbar, you can use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for finding the missing headers.

[image: Fiddler main window]

#### Option #3

You can also use a tool like [hurl.it](http://hurl.it) in order to test the headers expected by the target server as you discover them. IMO, this tool can be more straight forward than Fiddler during the debugging phase.

### Get back to your code

Once you have identified the missing headers, add them to your Java code like this:

```
URL url = new URL(GET_EXPENSE_FOR_VENDOR_URL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Missing-Header-1", "...");
conn.setRequestProperty("Missing-Header-2", "...");
```